# How to center block by vertical center?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="home__buttons">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="displayButton">
          <label>{{'step4_text_button1' | translate}} </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="displayButton">
          <label>{{'step4_text_button2' | translate}} </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now this is aligned horizontally, also I tried to align this by vertical center using position: absolute, but this rule breaks bootstrap styles.

Also I tried flex:

```
.home__buttons {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: there is no element in your code with ID `home__buttons`

Comment: @Chipster no, no, just no

Comment: @j08691 Nvm. Just realized this is asking about bootstrap.

Comment: Do it the bootstrap way or the plain CSS way. To attempt to find a middle ground is insanity (and also why attempting to use bootstrap is necessarily always insanity).

Comment: `home__buttons` is a class, not an id, also I think you want `justify-content` instead of `align-content`

Comment: add your css code

Comment: I fixed `.home__buttons` it is class, also have added CSS

Comment: As a side note, `<label>` elements are inappropriate here as there is nothing to label, `<span>`s would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to correct:

1. .home__buttons class should have the following properties:

   ```
   .home__buttons {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   ```

   }

   The class should be added to column cells, not the parent div.

   ```
   <div class="col-md-6 home__buttons">
   ```
2. The label is having a default margin-bottom in bootstrap, you can remove it by applying m-0 class on `<label>` tag.

   ```
   <label class="m-0">
   ```

Link to JS Fiddle(I applied borders to clearly see the layout): https://jsfiddle.net/srijan1709/nhfyx6ge/13/

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
.home_buttons
{
vertical-align:middle;
}
```